# Translation tag definition

Tags: discussion

Do generic questions regarding the translation of Hebrew phrases, with no relation to scholarly (i.e. torah related) text — such as this [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/139188/33217), fall under the scope of the translation [tag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/translation/info) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[No, they don't fall within scope of the site as a whole.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

(One may find the wording of the "translation" tag confusing. "Questions about translation in general, or about translation of specific words in Jewish texts." But it must be understood in context. Questions that are otherwise topical for the site are within the tag's scope if they're about translation; asking what *bayit* means, absent a Judaism context, is off-topic.)